# Can all isolation exercises be alternated side-to-side?

Tags: strength-training, training, exercise-technique, isolation

I was curious to know the following.

[image]

Since plenty of Isolation exercises out there have the capacity to be alternated...hence: by having a unilateral nature such as the concentration curl, they can be performed on both sides of the body in a split fashion, my question would be (and since I can't remember right now an isolation exercise that's bilateral or "not suitable for alternation")...Are all isolation exercises "alternatable"?.

Even if the answer to the previous is NO, I pose a second question: are all alternatable exercises necessarily isolation, or is it possible to find compound ones as well.
Thanks, I hope I made myself clear and not sound confusing.

Comment: All exercises have variations, I’m not sure what you’re asking.

Comment: Please stop posting questions in all capital letters.

Comment: I would remind everybody of the Be Nice policy. Name calling, bigotry and harassment will not be tolerated.

Answer (score 2):

No, not all isolation exercises are alternatable, and not all alternatable exercises are isolation exercises.

Examples of non-alternatable isolation exercises: Any articulation of the spine in the sagittal plane, including sit-ups, back extensions, neck flexion and extension.

Examples of alternatable compound movements: Split squats, one legged squats, single leg leg press, single arm dumbbell bench press, single arm dumbbell overhead press.